# Change the default scene grid color

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is it possible to change the default scene grid color (I'm using Unity 2017.1.1 Personal)?

When I don't have a `directional light` component, it has this ugly brown color:

[image]

Can this be done?

Comment: The brown colour isn't the grid, its the colour of the default Skybox. If you change your Skybox material to something else (maybe something from the asset store) then the brown colour will disappear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the grid line color by going to *Edit* ---> *Preferences* ---> *Colors* and then changing the Grid color.

[image]

For the background color, the grid does not have a background color. What you see is the default skybox image.

*Windows* ---> *Lightning* ---> *Settings* then go to Scene tab and remove the Skybox Material. Set it to "None". You can also create new material then use "Skybox/Procedural" as your material.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After `change color` you may need toggle `skybox` on the `scene` window. 
[image: toggle skybox on the scene Unity3D]

Unity3D 2018.3